# getNumberOfInteriorNodes BinaryTree Java

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

After what @hyde told me, this is what I did:

```
Node<E> current = root;
int count = 0;

public int getNumberOfInteriorNodes() {
    if (current == null || (current.left == null && current.right == null)) {
        return count;
    }
    else {
        if (current.right != null) {
            Node<E> tmp = current;
            current = current.right;
            count += getNumberOfInteriorNodes();
            current = tmp;
          }
          if (current.left != null) {
              Node<E> tmp = current;
              current = current.left;
              count += getNumberOfInteriorNodes();
              current = tmp;
          }
          return count + 1;
      }
}
```

Below is what my test method looks like:

```
public static void testGetNumberOfInteriorNodes() {
     BinarySearchTree<Integer> t;
     t = new BinarySearchTree<Integer>();
     Assert.assertEquals(0, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
     t.add(2);
     Assert.assertEquals(0, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
     t.add(1);
     Assert.assertEquals(1, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
     t.add(5);
     Assert.assertEquals(1, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
     t.add(4);
     Assert.assertEquals(2, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
     t.add(3);
     Assert.assertEquals(3, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
     t.add(6);
     Assert.assertEquals(3, t.getNumberOfInteriorNodes());
}
```

My test fails at the 3rd assertion with the error. Count never goes above zero. Here is the error I get:

```
Failure: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<0>
```

Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: If a node didn't have any children it would be a *leaf* node, not an *interior* node.

Comment: You assign **count** to zero at the beginning of each call to _getNumberOfInteriorNodes()_. I don't know if this could be causing your problem.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen isn't that what this line does:

`code`if (current==null||root==null||(current.left==null&&current.right==null)){
      return count;
    }`\code`

If not, can you suggest an improvement. I've been working on this for far to long...

Comment: @AcId Ty for suggestion, I put count outside the method but it does not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, you have just one shared `current` variable when you are using recursion. It will get overwritten in recursive calls. Instead, you must pass it as parameter, so your recursive function needs to be:

```
public int getNumberOfInteriorNodes(Node<E> current)
```

And on *first* call (somewhere else in your code) you pass `root` to it:

```
... = getNumberOfInteriorNodes(root);
```

Then you need to pass modified value in recursive call, for right side:

```
count += getNumberOfInteriorNodes(current.right);
```

And same for left side, naturally. No `return` here, otherwise it would return and not calculate the other side! Also no +1, if both right and left side exist then it would be +2. Instead, `return count + 1;` at the end of the method (yep, you do need it).

---

Also, in your first `if`, no point testing if `root == null`, it does not do anything useful (nothing harmful either *in this case*, but it's still clutter which makes it harder understand the code, and may become a problem if you change the code).

---

Then you also seem to have this: `int count==0;;`

Does that even compile, or is it a copy-paste error?  You should use assignment `int count = 0;`

---

If you have limitation of not having parameters for the method, you need to restore value of `current` after the call. Here's code for the right side, do same for the left side:

```
if (current.right!=null) {
    Node<E> tmp = current;
    current = current.right;
    count += getNumberOfInteriorNodes();
    current = tmp;
}
```

Note that for "real" code, this would be quite a stupid way to do recursion.

If this "no parameters" is just API limitation, then the usual way to solve this is with a private helper method:

```
public int getNumberOfInteriorNodes() {
    return recNumberOfInteriorNodes(root) 
}

private int recNumberOfInteriorNodes(Node<E> current) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: He's counting interior nodes, so he does need it to be `return count + 1;`. His base case will catch it if it is not an interior node.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the parameter. I am not allowed to have any parameters for this method. Is there a way to do the same thing you did above but without using parameters?

Comment: @user2262746 Yep, you can do it by using local variable to store value of `current`. I'll add that to my answer. But note that it's totally stupid to do it that way :)

Comment: @hyde your help is really appreciated. I edited my post with what I attempted. Please see if you can help me out further. Thanks!

Comment: @user2262746 About new code: count needs to be local variable of the method (like in your original code). Otherwise it too will get clobbered. Alternatively you can change the return type to `void`, remove return statements, and just modify `count` directly inside the method.

Comment: @hyde thanks for suggestion. I put int count=0; inside the method but still get the same error

Comment: @hyde thanks so much! The way you said at the beginning was correct. Used a private helper method and made it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that does the trick. Btw: Nodes with no children are `leaves`.

```
class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
}

class Main {
    void test() {
        Node root = new Node();
        Node leftleft = new Node();
        Node left = new Node();
        Node right = new Node();
        Node rightright = new Node();
        Node rightleft = new Node();
        root.left = left;
        root.right = right;
        left.left = leftleft;
        right.left = rightleft;
        right.right = rightright;
        int c = getLeaves(root);
    }

    int getLeaves(Node node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) 
            return 1;
        return getLeaves(node.left) + getLeaves(node.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this without using parameters. Thanks though.